# Inner product and the dual

Tags: functional-analysis

I am tryig to sort of how inner products and duals are related. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair it donst seem possible to use an inner product when we define the natural dual pairing, yet Riesz theorem tells us that any functional is given by the innerproduct.

Does anyone have an idea how this add up?

Comment: The dual pair is defined for a general banach space, in which case we don't necessarily have an inner product or Riesz representation theorem (the usual one, anyways). It is similar to the inner product in that it is a bilinear map but inner product spaces are special because the dual space is the same vector space we started with.

Comment: @TonyS.F. regardless as a special case it should work, right?

Comment: Well, for _real_ Hilbert spaces. In the complex case, the inner product is sesquilinear, and the dual pairing bilinear.

Comment: @DanielFischer But the inner product is defined on $V \times V$ not on the dual so how can it become a dual pairing?

Comment: A dual pairing is defined on $E \times F$, and nothing forbids $E = F$ in that.

Comment: @DanielFischer no, but then thats not the dual? Say for the sake of argument that we are in an L^p space and p is not 2

Comment: if $p$ is not 2 then you don't have a Hilbert space and $E\neq F$.

Comment: Are you considering only the dual pairing on a vector space and a subspace of its algebraic dual, or are you considering the general situation of dual pairs?

Comment: @DanielFischer the former, the topological dual in particular.

Comment: In that case: an element of $V$ is a different type of thing from a linear map $V \to K$ (where $K$ is the scalar field). The Riesz map gives an isomorphism (or anti-isomorphism in the complex case) between a Hilbert space and its topological dual, so we can write the elements of the dual as $\langle\,\cdot\mathbin{\mid} v\rangle$, but that's an entirely different thing than $v$ is. The natural pairing would then be $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle \colon ( v, \langle\,\cdot\mathbin{\mid} w\rangle) \mapsto \langle v \mathbin{\mid} w\rangle$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I dont understand that last expression. Is that a bilinear form taking arguments $v$ and $w$? Is it a compistion of two biliear maps?

Comment: No, $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ is the pairing between the inner product space and its dual. $\langle\,\cdot\mathbin{\mid}\cdot\,\rangle$ is the inner product. And $\langle \,\cdot\mathbin{\mid} w\rangle$ is the image of $w$ under the Riesz map, that is, the linear functional $\varphi_w \colon v \mapsto \langle v\mathbin{\mid} w\rangle$. This way, we can write it as $\langle v, \varphi_w\rangle = \langle v\mathbin{\mid} w\rangle$.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah so the dual pairing is just the action of the functional which in turn is represented as a inner product! The pairing is not the inner product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Fichers comment,

No, $⟨⋅,⋅⟩$ is the pairing between the inner product space and its dual. $⟨⋅∣⋅⟩$ is the inner product. And $⟨⋅∣w⟩$ is the image of ww under the Riesz map, that is, the linear functional $φ_{w}:v↦⟨v∣w⟩$. This way, we can write it as $⟨v,φ_{w}⟩=⟨v∣w⟩$